# Angular 9: formData.append('key', null) actually appends 'null' string

Tags: angular, multipartform-data, angular-httpclient

Using Typescript/Angular 9:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('key', null);
console.log(formData.get('key'));

>> 'null'
```

this is a 'null' string, as opposed to `null` value.

I need to somehow append null (or undefined) value to the `FormData`. What can I do?

Comment: you can send  like ''

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't, because the value is always converted to a string if it's not a `USVString` or `Blob`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

> The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including
>   subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is
>   converted to a string.

However, if you delete a key and try to access it, it will return null by default.

```
let oFormData: FormData = new FormData();

oFormData.append('key1', null);
oFormData.get('key1'); // string 'null'
oFormData.delete('key1');
console.log(oFormData.get('key1')); // null
```

Answer (score 24):

Any value passed into data.append will be converted to a string. The only way to accomplish sending a null value is the send an empty string. i.e. `formData.append('key', '');` This will send a null value to the backend without stringifying it.

Comment: Thanks, server see boolean "null"))

Answer (score -2):

Try to set `key` to `undefined`:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('key', undefined);
console.log(formData.get('key'));
```

Comment: It returns "undefined" as String. How does that help?